# Как удалить повторы на JS

Tags: jquery, javascript, get

Есть запрос на получение некой информации:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
 $.getJSON('/test.php', function(data) {
  alert(data.num); // некие значения
 });
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Для интереса, если в **num** выпадает **5 одинаковых значений** (например alert(1) выпадет 5 раз), то **4 нужно удалить** и вывести 1. И всё это на JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант - записывать выпавшие числа в массив и перед выводом проверять, что такого еще не было (используется jQuery)

```
var nums = [];
setInterval(function() {
   $.getJSON('/test.php', function(data) {
      if ($.inArray(data.num, nums)) {
          alert(data.num); // некие значения
          nums.push(data.num);    
      }
   });
}, 2000);
```

Если имеется в виду, что нельзя выводить одинаковые числа подряд, то просто запоминать последнее число и сравнивать с ним перед выводом

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
function remove (data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        for(var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++)
            if(data[i] == data[j])
                data.splice(j, 1);
    return data;
}
```

---

```
var data = ['data1',2,3,2,1,'data4',5,6,'data3',8,9,'data4',5,2,'data1'];
console.log(remove(data)); //["data1", 2, 3, 1, "data4", 5, 6, "data3", 8, 9]
```